# automatic date and time picking -React Native

Tags: react-native, datepicker

In React-native i want to automatically pick system date and time and display in two Textinput place. how can i do this? both time and date must assigned to variables.

Answer (score 0):

you can use JS Date as usual

for example:

```
var currentdate = new Date(); 
var datetime = "Current date: " + currentdate.getDate() + "/"
            + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
            + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
            + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
            + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
            + currentdate.getSeconds();
```